# Using a small brush size with color replacement (cs6) results in image blur

Tags: photoshop

I am a newbie with Photoshop. I tried to use color replacement in CS6 and have read lots of tutorials about this.

My problem is I want to change a color in a picture and when I use color replacement with a normal brush size it makes the picture blur, but when I use a larger brush size, e.g. 500px, it is ok

For example :

main photo :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNfkq.jpg

edited photo :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhZwH.jpg

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the larger brush then!

If that results in you changing more of the picture than you wanted (brush too large to be accurate), then use a mask (and a smaller brush) to mask in/out the areas that you want.

So:

1) Create a layer
2) Use 500px brush to change your color
3) Add a black mask to the image - this will hide all your color changes
4) Use a 70px (or whatever size works) white brush and paint in the mask the areas you want changed